# Transfer Eth through smart contract to other account?

Tags: smartcontracts, transfer, ether

In the below code eth will be transferred in the form of Wei by default, but I want the amount will transfer in the form of Ether, how can I do that?

```
function (uint amount) public payable {
someaddress.transfer(amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wei is the smallest unit of Ether, specifically 1 ETH == 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 (or 1e18) wei.

The `transfer()` function always accepts the amount in wei. So if you want to pass just `1` as the input param, meaning that you want to send 1 full ETH, you can multiply the value by 1e18 effectively converting ETH to wei.

```
function (uint ethAmount) public payable {
    uint weiAmount = ethAmount * 1e18;
    someaddress.transfer(weiAmount);
}
```

---

Note: There's also the [ether](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units) global unit, but in the current Solidity version (0.8), this can be used only in combination with number literals - not with variables.

```
uint weiAmount = 1 ether; // ok
```

```
uint weiAmount = ethAmount ether; // syntax error
```

Comment: that I know, I thought maybe there's some other method to it btw thanks

Comment: @Tarandeepsingh What do you mean by other method? Can you say in other words what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: like in web3.js we use utils to convert wei to ether I thought maybe something the same in solidity

Comment: @Tarandeepsingh You can divide/multiply by 1e18 (which is "one and eighteen zeros") to calculate ether to/from wei. Mind that there's no decimal number type in Solidity, so that's why all units are usually in wei. I.e. you cannot use `0.1` (of ETH) so you use `100000000000000000` (of wei).